# include cakePHP element on ajax success

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cakephp

I have a javascript code which makes an Ajax request to a URL and on success (in the success callback) call a cakePHP element like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "the_url_where_the_request_should_go",
    success: function(data) {
        "<?php echo $this->element('the_path_to_my_element'); ?>";
    }
});
```

As you can see, because I am in javascript code, I have to put double quotes ("") around my PHP tags for this to work. The problem I'm having is that in the success function, when I call my element, the double quotes are sent along. Meaning, if the code in my element file is for example:

```
<div>element_code_here</div>
```

I get:

```
"<div>element_code_here</div>" (notice the double quotes gets included also)
```

Does anybody know why it's doing this and how can I fix this?

By the way, if I just remove the double quotes around my PHP tags, it just won't work (it gives me a javascript Invalid Identifier error message.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Still struggling with this one?

Answer (score 0):

The success callback is still a javascript function so you need to treat the element you are echoing with PHP as a string.  I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish and I would probably suggest returning the element (html) from your ajax endpoint instead of interpolating it directly into the script but using your example you should do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "the_url_where_the_request_should_go",
    success: function(data) {
        var html_string = "<?php echo $this->element('the_path_to_my_element'); ?>";
        //do something with the html string.. like insert it into a waiting div
        $('div.container').html(html_string);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess. Try returning element from server with something like this:

```
//Function to call with $.ajax

function giveElement($elementName){

    //logic to do with POST


    //element to return
    $this->render('/elements/'.$elementName);


}
//NOT TESTED. This might need something else too.
```